# I rehomed my dog’s puppy and I’ve been emotional

Tags: dogs, adoption

After I release two of my dog’s puppy I became too emotional that I really feel depressed. I always thought that they might feel alone and look for their mother and siblings and also our family became so attached to them. I feel so sad even knowing that they’re going to be with a loving owner too. 
I don’t know if this is normal, it’s been 3 days.

Is there a way to cope up with this mentality?
Or any tips for me to assure that they are going to be fine.

Comment: If you want help with the pet - part of your problem  (like "how to organise? What facts to ask the new owners? ...) this is the right place. If you want help for the mentally side  (How to deal with the feelings) you could ask a question with this point in interpersonal.SE

Comment: @Allerleirauh FWIW that aspect would be off topic at Interpersonal Skills as well as it's about dealing with the OP's own internal emotions - not interacting with another person.

Comment: @motosubatu agreed. Only how to deal with the new owners...

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is to ask the new owner for updates. It's always hard rehoming pets, but sometimes it is necessary, as we have our limits on how many pets we can care for. If you can focus on the puppy's frame of reference it makes it easier. Dog's are adaptable, especially puppies. They respond to love and consistency. In a loving home, the puppy will be happy and possibly have more attention. Focus on the aspects the new owners could give the puppy that you could not.

Ask the new owner to send you pictures, if they are on social media, perhaps you can connect and share the adventures of the puppy in her new home.

The other thing to prevent this from happening again is to neuter your dog to prevent her from having more litters.